# Dancer2 Session Not written to file

Tags: perl, dancer

In my Dancer2 app I find that the session information is not stored in between file request. I am using YAML as my session store format.

e.g.

I have defined a test route to set a variable in the session and dump the settings and session variable in the template using Data Dumper in the template.

```
get '/test' => sub {
session("a"=>1);
template 'test';
};
```

The result of Data Dumper is

```
$VAR1 = {
'engines' => {
'template' => {
'template_toolkit' => {
'start_tag' => '<%',
'end_tag' => '%>'
}
},
'session' => {
'YAML' => {
'cookie_name' => 'domain.session',
'is_secure' => '1',
'is_http_only' => '1',
'session_dir' => '/tmp/dancer-sessions/'
}
}
},
```

And session var is

```
$VAR1 = {
'a' => 1
};
```

At this point I expect my /tmp directory to contain a session folder but I see the following

```
starman@ubuntu:~/www/app$ ls -al /tmp
total 776
drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root      4096 Apr  2 14:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root    root      4096 Apr  2 07:31 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 starman starman 776737 Apr  2 14:31 starman.err
-rw-r--r--  1 starman starman      0 Apr  2 07:31 starman.out
-rw-r--r--  1 starman starman      4 Apr  2 14:31 starman.pid
```

I am unable to figure out why the session file is not getting created. Any pointers on my mistake will be helpful

**EDIT**
Adding more information.
I have modified the test route to take 2 parameters key and value which are stored in the session as follows.

```
get '/test/:key/:value' => sub {
my $key =params->{key};
my $value =params->{value};
session($key=>$value);
template 'test';};
```

My test.tt is as follows

```
<%USE Dumper%>
<h1> Dumping the settings variable </h1>
<%Dumper.dump_html(settings)%>
<h1> Dumping the session variable </h1>
<%Dumper.dump_html(session)%>
```

The live url for this route is

[Live URL](http://edaindia.com/test/var/bar)

I still do not see any folder being created in my /tmp/ folder

Comment: This may seem like a dumb question, but did you actually send a request? If so, did you get a valid response (HTTP 200 and the contents of your test template)?

Comment: Yes I did, The code snippet for the $Var1's is from the response html pages.

Comment: Try turning logging all the way up and check the logs after making a request.

Comment: The log level is already set to core, Making a request is not resulting in any error message.

Comment: Did you remove that test installation? I get a Dancer 404.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this with the skeleton app generated by `dancer2`. Run `dancer2 gen -a Foo` to generate a new app and see if you can reproduce the issue. Change the session engine in config.yml, but don't change anything else, then send a request. If the directory is created, figure out what's different between your app and the generated one; if it's not created, edit your config.yml into the question.

Comment: Yes, I removed the test route, I had a lengthy debug session with the folks on the #dancer channel @irc.perl.org and resolved most of the issues with sessions.

Comment: @vijayvithal In that case, can you please write an answer so future visitors with the same issue can see how you fixed it?

Comment: My learning were as follows. 1. The config.yml file is sensitive to indentation, 2. all engines should be grouped together  3. We need to define template, session and session_name at global level

Comment: @vijayvithal Can you post your original broken config file and your working config file in an answer (not a comment)? I think that would be really helpful for people in the future.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I seem to be having the same problem, in this case with the log itself.

Comment: Yes it was resolved. Check my comment above. The problem was related to indentation and grouping of plugins